# Can't understand the output of this python code (loop on a list)

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops

can someone explains how this code works step by step?

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
for a[-1] in a:
  print(a[-1])
```

Output:
0
1
2
2

Answer (score 0):

`a[-1]` after the `for` causes the last element of the list to be overwritten on each iteration. If you modify it a bit you can see what's going on better:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
for a[-1] in a:
    print(a)

[0, 1, 2, 0]
[0, 1, 2, 1]
[0, 1, 2, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 2]
```

`a` produces a `0`, then `1`, then a `2`, then, it gets to the last element in the list that's been overwritten previously, and it already contains a `2`, so it gets replaced back.

Answer (score -1):

Just think of this.
`for a[-1] in a`
First takes the first element from a and replaces it with `a[-1]` which is the last element.
In the next step, it takes the second value and puts it in `a[-1]`which again is the last element. And so on and so on.
The `print(a[-1])`statement just prints the last element in each loop.

Comment: `"takes the first element from a and replaces it with a[1] which ist the last element"` —It does not replace the first element with anything, and a[1] is not the last element.

Comment: 'replaces'. Forgot to mention, its  ```a[-1]``` not ```a[1]```. My bad, im so sorry.